# Table of contents in a tabular environment - how to align horizontal lines between entries?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, horizontal

**Problem:** I am trying to put a table of contents into a table so that an agenda tick list can be automatically generated from sections/subsections titles that have been defined in another file. Redefining`\cftsecafterpnum` and `\cftsubsecafterpnum` to include horizontal lines is starting the line at the section/subsection indent and not the left border of the table.

**What I have tried:** I tried setting `\setlength\cftsecindent{(value)}` and `\setlength\cftsubsecindent{(value)}` to negative values so as to bring the horizontal line over to the left border of the table but naturally it moved the section/subsection headings to the left too. Using `\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}` with `\hrule` threw an error and `\hrulefill` produced lines only underneath the entries indent and not spanning the table like this:

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,inner=2.3cm,outer=2.3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{-16pt}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}

\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{%
    \vskip0.2cm \line(1,0){15cm}
}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{%
    \vskip0.2cm \line(1,0){14cm}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\newpage

\def\arraystretch{2}

\begin{tabular}{ |p{6.8cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{2.2cm}|  }

\multicolumn{5}{c}{\Large\bfseries Title} \\
\hline
\hfil\textbf{Section}\hfil & \textbf{Decisions?} & \textbf{Actions?} & \textbf{Dates?}  & \textbf{Completed?}\\
\hline
\tableofcontents & & & &\\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It currently looks like this:

[image: Current table look]

The formatting of the entries doesn't look good as I stripped out all the formatting commands for the MWE so please ignore the entries aesthetics. I would like for there to be horizontal lines that span the entire table from left to right border after TOC entries and for the extra space underneath 2.1 Subsection to be removed. I couldn't find an option in `tocloft` for removing space *after* the TOC if it is even a `tocloft` setting, I am not sure what is causing that space underneath 2.1 Subsection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not perfect whatsoever and I still have much to learn, but the answer was to just remove the section/subsection numbers and modify the `\cftsetindents` values.

The last space was caused by the &'s after `\tableofcontents & & & &\\`.

Working code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,inner=2.3cm,outer=2.3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{-16pt}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}

\def\numberline#1{}             % Gets rid of page numbers in TOC entries
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{-0.58em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0em}{-0.58em}

\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{%
    \vskip0.2cm \line(1,0){15.5cm}
}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{%
    \vskip0.2cm \line(1,0){15.5cm}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\newpage

\def\arraystretch{2}

\begin{tabular}{ |p{6.8cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{2.2cm}|  }

\multicolumn{5}{c}{\Large\bfseries Title} \\
\hline
\hfil\textbf{Section}\hfil & \textbf{Decisions?} & \textbf{Actions?} & \textbf{Dates?}  & \textbf{Completed?}\\
\hline
\tableofcontents
Meeting Complete & & & & \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How it looks:

[image]

Need to manually change dimensions to line table up if changing page sizes etc but it works for now.

Comment: I have accepted my own answer as it was bugging me on my profile and to stop @community bumping it again so my apologies for it appearing once more.